# Java: How to return single char after string

Tags: java, string, search

I have a file directory which could look like either

```
C:\projects\lab3\test\test.java
```

or

```
C:\projects\assignment3\test\test.java
```

But the "lab3" or "assignment3" can appear anywhere in the directory, it is not a set directory

What i want is to check to see if the directory either contains "lab" or "assignment" and get the number that follows. In this case "3"

This is what i have so far

```
 if(directory.toLowerCase().contains("lab")){

 } else if (directory.toLowerCase().contains("assignment")){

 }
```

but i do not know how to check for the char straight after the word?

Comment: You can use String#substring to extract the part after the "lab" and then use Integer.parseInt to get it as number.

Comment: You do realise that it not possible to know at runtime where the source came from. i.e. there is no way to get the `directory`

Comment: but how would i use the substring to get directly after "lab"? that is the problem i am having

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: I have the directory, I am getting it when I choose the file using a JFileChooser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you are asking for:

```
String directory = "C:\\projects\\lab3\\test\\test.java";
if(directory.toLowerCase().contains("lab")){
 System.out.println(directory.substring(directory.indexOf("lab")+3,   directory.indexOf("lab")+4));

         }
```

The +3 parameter is because of the size of "lab" String. You can do better this way:

```
String directory = "C:\\projects\\lab3\\test\\test.java";
String myWord = "lab";
if(directory.toLowerCase().contains(myWord)){
  System.out.println(directory.substring(directory.indexOf(myWord)+ myWord.length(), directory.indexOf(myWord)+ myWord.length()+1));

         }
```

Comment: cheers, this is exactly what i am looking, this way allows me to search for where 'lab' or 'assignment' is and then work from there... thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(?:lab|assignment)([0-9]).*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String substr = pattern.matcher(directory).replaceAll("$1");
```

This gets any single-digit number after the last occurrence of either "lab" or "assignment" in the string.

For this to work, you need to import the following classes:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Comment: I'd think you don't need .* at the beginning or the end, as you're not using $ or ^, so it's not checking for line start or end anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String#substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to extract the part after the "lab" and then use [Integer#parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) to check it's an integer and convert it.

```
String partAfterLab = filename.substring(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression like `C:\\\\projects\\\\(lab|assignment)([0-9]+)\\\\.*` to extract the digit(s) after "lab" or "assignment".

Answer (score 0):

use regex

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String dir = "C:\\projects\\lab3\\test\\test.java";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?(lab)(\\d+).*");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dir);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //contains lab
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); //contains number
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
Integer.valueOf(s.replaceFirst(".*(assignment|lab)([0-9]+).*", "$2"));
```

For example:

```
String assignment = "C:\\projects\\assignment3\\test\\test.java";
String lab = "C:\\projects\\lab3\\test\\test.java";
String none = "C:\\projects\\test\\test.java";

try {
    int assignmentNumber = Integer.valueOf(assignment.replaceFirst(".*(assignment|lab)([0-9]+).*", "$2"));
    System.out.println(assignmentNumber);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Can't find neither assignment nor lab");
}

try {
    int labNumber = Integer.valueOf(lab.replaceFirst(".*(assignment|lab)([0-9]+).*", "$2"));
    System.out.println(labNumber);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Can't find neither assignment nor lab");
}

try {
    int noneNumber = Integer.valueOf(none.replaceFirst(".*(assignment|lab)([0-9]+).*", "$2"));
    System.out.println(noneNumber);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Can't find neither assignment nor lab");
}
```

Prints:

```
3
3
Can't find neither assignment nor lab
```